# show dbs command only listing admin, local, config

Tags: mongodb

i am new to mongodb environment working on a project front end, i need to setup the test database created by backend team on my local machine.
I installed the mongod and copied the files given by my team into c:/data/db and started the db with mongod command. I was able to run loopback api on localhost fine for the first time with all the project data.
Suddenly today when I try to use the same local api server (after starting mongo),it was showing the collections but there is not data inside the collections. When i did 'show dbs' command, it is only showing config, admin and local with each 0.00GB size.
Can anyone help me how to fix it and where i was going wrong. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you expect `show dbs` will show to you actually?